# С помощью forEach, переберите массив

Tags: javascript

Дан массив a9 = ['Quantum Break', 'Gears of War 4', 'Mass Effect: Andromeda', 'Far Cry Primal']. С помощью forEach, переберите массив a9 и преобразуйте все записи в массиве в нижний регистр. Действия должны запускаться при вызове функции t9. Функция должна возвращать a9.
Что-то застрял((( перепробовал много методов

```
         let a9 = ['Quantum Break', 'Gears of War 4', 'Mass Effect: Andromeda', 'Far Cry Primal'];
        function t9() {
    
    
        a9.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item.toLowerCase());
    
        });
    
        return a9
       }
        document.querySelector('.b-9').onclick = () => {
        console.log(t9());
       }
 <section>
                <p><b>Task 09.</b></p>
                <p>
                    Дан массив a9 = ['Quantum Break', 'Gears of War 4', 'Mass
                    Effect: Andromeda', 'Far Cry Primal']. С помощью forEach,
                    переберите массив a9 и преобразуйте все записи в массиве в
                    нижний регистр. Действия должны запускаться при вызове
                    функции t9. Функция должна возвращать a9.
                </p>
                <button class="b-9 button-primary">task 9</button>
            </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let a9 = ['Quantum Break', 'Gears of War 4', 'Mass Effect: Andromeda', 'Far Cry Primal'];

function t9() {


    a9.forEach(function (e, i) {
        a9[i] = e.toLowerCase()

    });

    return a9
}

document.querySelector('.b-9').onclick = () => {
    console.log(t9());
}
```

Comment: Сам нашёл решение

Comment: такой forEach работает медленнее, чем из lodash. имейте в виду.